# How much do bounties increase the likelihood of getting a good/acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

There's currently 444 bounties on SO, including one I've just added myself, but statistically speaking, does putting a bounty on your question actually lead to an increase in the chances of getting an answer **good enough to be accepted**? If so, by how much on average?

Comment: Yes, you'll get an answer.  Whether it is the one you actually want still heavily depends on the question, no shortcut for that.

Comment: For a high quality question in a niche area, a bounty raises the probability that one of the few experts who can answer it exhaustively will actually notice it.

Comment: [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/) may help (especially if you want to discriminate only by accepted answers regardless their _quality_ - pretty hard to evaluate).

Comment: Hmm, I'd be wary of drawing too many conclusions from data mining. It might well be that those who offer bounties are more, or less, likely to accept an answer than those who don't. (Maybe they feel honour-bound to give the bounty to someone; maybe they demand higher standards; in any case bounties aren't likely to be offered by the many newish users who just can't be bothered to accept an answer regardless of how good it is.)

Comment: You can put bounties on someone else's question, therefore the accepted answer may not be the one which got the bounty.

Comment: From personal experience you won't get an answer if the question is difficult or in a niche area as there are simply not enough people in those areas to answer the question in the time limit of the bounty

Comment: @ClaraOnager I've found that, too. Bounties don't seem to attract experts, or have a big impact on the number of views/answers in my experience. Hmm.

Comment: I guess from an answering point of view - I'll generally answer a question if I can. The only thing that really changes this is the visibility of it. A bountied question 'stands out' a bit more. I might also be prepared to put a more detailed answer if the questioner is 'paying' for it. 
But overall, it doesn't much change my likelihood of trying to answer.

Comment: I'll wait for a bounty to answer this.

Comment: The analysis in the accepted answer to "[Does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238736/262755)" may be useful to you.

Comment: I think this would be a good question to ask on Statistics.SE, as it's so specific a question that only a statistician is qualified to answer.

Comment: Do bounties get precedence in the "Interesting" tab on the home page? seems the only two bounties i see on my home page currently are there due to being edited or answered recently. Therefore, anyone who's answering questions based on the "Interesting" tab would not generally answer bountied questions any more than normal questions. (unless they singled out the question specifically for the rep)

Comment: For what its worth, I offered a bounty over on UX.  Before I posted the bounty, I got a couple meh quality answers.  After posting the bounty, I got a whole bunch of meh quality answers.

Comment: On [su], whenever someone puts a bounty on a question, it's **almost always** answered by harrymc, the highest rep user on that site, on the same day (at the most a day or two) after the bounty is placed (unless it was put to reward an existing answer).

Comment: I once placed a bounty on a question about an extremely obscure corner case in the python GUI library traitsui on stackoverflow that I really could have used an answer to. Nobody even tried to answer it (which is a good thing, maybe?).

Comment: I hardly ever click onto the featured tab so am only likely to notice bountied questions if they pop up on the active questions.

Comment: _waits for somebody to write a data explorer query_

Comment: In my experience, bounties only attract bounty hunters.  They know that a really poor (if not totally bogus) answer can get the bounty if no one else answers.  The folks who really know their stuff generally have enough points that a bounty is of no real interest to them.

Comment: I put a bounty on a question asking if there was a way to make Dropbox storage visible on the filesystem without having a local copy taking up space. Basically all the answers I got were variants of "That's useless, no one would ever use that feature."

Comment: @FatalKeystroke I would *love* that feature.

Comment: Here's a [question and answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238736/21960) that covers a lot of the same ground, with some analysis by a Stack Exchange dev.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a query in [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to see if there's any sort of correlation:

### [Data Explorer - Do Bounties Increase the Chances of Getting an Accepted Answer?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/463131/do-bounties-increase-the-chances-of-getting-an-accepted-answer)

The results appear to be as follows:

**34%** of **questions without Bounties** (and a score of >= 0) have an accepted answer.

Interestingly, if we only include questions with a **Score of 1 or higher**, this leaps to **48%**.

And again, if we only include questions with a **Score of 2 or higher**, this leaps again to **56%**.

Questions with a **Score of 3 or higher** and it's **61%**(!).

**56%** of **questions WITH Bounties** have an accepted answer. (The same as if a non-Bountied question has a score of 2 or higher.)

(There's reason to argue why this Bountied percentage may be artificially higher, too: Users are frequently reminded to reward a Bounty once the time has ended, possibly leading to the acceptance of an answer, even if it's not perfect, for example.)

## Conclusion

It seems that, provided you've asked a high quality Question in the first place (worthy of a score of >= 1), the chances of getting an answer that is worthy of accepting does **not** hugely increase with the addition of a Bounty, and with a well received Question (>= 2), it may not help at all.

A question with a score of 0 may be the result of the obscurity of the subject, and a Bounty may increase the chances of it being seen, but this is only speculation.

There's still more questions to answer, such as does the size of the Bounty have any effect on the chances of getting an answer worthy of accepting, and whether the answer you get from a Bounty are higher quality on average than those without, but from this brief exploration it seems the Bounty system does not necessarily dramatically increase the odds of getting a better answer.

Answer (score 22):

Statistically speaking, I have no idea.

Anecdotally speaking, bounties are a toss-up. For difficult questions (the ones I find I need bounties on, since otherwise the question scrolls off before it gets enough attention), they attract a lot of poor answers from people who didn't actually read the question and think I'm asking something much simpler. But I still eventually get an answer that provides at least some value, even if not fully solving the original problem. I'd estimate my success rate at getting good (even if not complete) answers from bounties somewhere between 50 and 75 percent, and, and my rate of getting really good answers substantially lower.

Comment: *...they attract a lot of poor answers from people who didn't actually read the question and think I'm asking something much simpler.* -- So true

Comment: Of course, if the question was that simple, you wouldn't need the bounty...

Answer (score 10):

Here's a very quick query to count the views on posts for the previous month (September 2014):

### [Data Explorer - Post View Count vs Bounty View Count](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/231657/how-much-attention-to-bounties-generate-on-posts)

**Results:**

```
AvgPostViewsSept2014 | AvgBountyViewsSept2014
=============================================
         35          |           114

114 / 35 = 3.257 (times more views with a bounty)
```

This is based on 238415 questions in that month. Not sure if that query is fully accurate as I just wrote it quickly and it doesn't take in to account closed or deleted questions and bouties are included in the first average.

But based on the view stats alone (ignoring the complexity of the question), you're more likely to have someone view it and answer if there are more people looking at it.

Comment: The question asked was about the effect of a bounty on a question, but a query like yours does not *isolate* the effect of the bounty from other factors. Questions that get bounties are probably going to be **good questions in the first place**, which people are interested to look at irrespective of the bounty. Why waste a bounty on something terrible?

Comment: @Louis I wasn't aiming to get into a deep analysis of bounties, I was merely illustrating that with more eyes on a problem you _might_ be more likely to get a _good/acceptable answer_.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't isolate views during the bounty period vs organic views.

Answer (score -3):

Statistically some questions should have a likely hood of producing an accepted answer with a bounty.

First it would depend on the type of question.  If you asked for the answer to a millennium problem on stack overflow I doubt the bounty would have any effect on you getting an answer.  Extreme examples aside, my point is that if the question wasn't answered because it was too hard or too much work to respond to then a bounty wouldn't have (much of) an effect.

The community has a wide variety of members.  Simplistically two ways to categorize them is by their motivation for points and their motivation to help people.  To illustrate my point, suppose those two populations are disjoint:  **Gamers** and **Helpers**. (I mean gamers in the sense that they game the system to get REP)  If your question doesn't attract **Helpers** but does attracts **Gamers** then bounties wouldn't matter.  Similarly for the reverse.

There is a finite amount of time people spend looking at questions.  One thing bounties DO do is that they put more attention on it.  Which for some people steals some of that attention away from non-bountied questions.  Even if their are some members who refuse to look at bountied questions, you would still get the original attention for the question so these people won't hurt your chances of getting an answer.