# Why do people care about reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, downvotes

I see people talk a lot on here about the amount of points they have, worries about people downvoting them, etc. Is there some advantage to having these points that I'm not aware of? I can't see why anyone would really care, so I feel I must be missing something here.

Comment: On meta?  Nobody cares.

Comment: No, there isn't any benefit apart from what Oded mentioned. The real benefit of participation is the knowledge you gain, the improvement in your communication skills, and the brilliant posts you get to read on these sites, and an opportunity to discuss these with other professionals in chat.

Comment: Check out Reddit(or don't) . people obsess over points there also

Comment: [I DON'T CARE](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=bounties) :Ь

Comment: @nicael: Way to go, see [minitech on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/160410/minitech?tab=bounties&sort=offered)

Comment: @Deduplicator I simply didn't earn that much rep to bounty :D

Comment: Look at how much rep nicael is left with @Deduplicator. He is a 200 rep user

Comment: Google "internet gamification".

Comment: There's an entire section in the [help] at SO (and here) about reputation and moderation that explains what reputation is and what it's used for here. Did you miss it?

Comment: I never saw ANYONE talking about reputation points directly. Or worrying about the downvotes they get. If someone does worry then I would say that it's a good thing, since it forces people to think more before posting and structure their thoughts better.

Comment: FWIW, I have been contacted for informal job interviews based solely on my SO rep, specifically in the C++ tag.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Similarly, I have been "probed" through SO Careers at about the same time I went over the 100k mark; I would not be surprised to see reputation used as a filter by recruiters.

Comment: Any practical use aside, I think it's just nice to be thanked/for someone to say they found what you wrote useful.

Comment: And btw, @Ded, he was a mod there earlier, so rep *of course* didn't matter for him.

Comment: Why do people care about "Why do people care about reputation points?". Different people care about different things. It is impossible to describe exactly why someone cares about something.

Comment: I do it to get more chicks

Comment: @OliverWatkins: In this community, you gotta make the rep first. Then when you get the rep, you get the power. Then when you get the power, then you get the women.

Comment: I think it forces you to think before you ask/answer questions which only benefits us I suppose in improving communication skills, and the ability to explain things. the points system is just to keep you going i guess?

Comment: The only thing i really care about rep for is being able to downvote. It really bugs me not being able to downvote on `meta.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: This question is certainly on-topic, since this is the Meta site for SO.

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason you've put the effort in to post a question here.

Comment: I find it amusing that my highest rep is on Math SE, and even more so given that most of it comes from a joke answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/454381/37944

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yeah, I got an employment inquiry from a very big name in the tech industry when I was in the top 0.0000001% (don't know exactly how many 0s) of Java worldwide for a while at the start of this year.

Comment: My personal sense of self worth is directly related to my StackExchange reputation.

Comment: In all honesty though, I think a little bit of validation of an individual post is a good thing - if my work is good, I appreciate it if several people say so.

Comment: Why do you equate "fight against downvotes" with "care about rep so much"? There are several other reasons for disliking downvotes and objecting to invalid ones... from the desire to correct mistakes and advance one's own programming knowledge (in the case of legitimate downvotes), to the desire to see the best content rise to the top benefiting future readers (which is an argument against tactical voting, voting based on the asker's style or lack of understanding, etc)  I promise you, any user over 20k who is talking about downvotes isn't primarily worried about the rep.

Comment: I've heard somewhere that with 1000K points you'll win a unicorn

Comment: @Dedup Ok, now [I am cooler](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=bounties&sort=offered) than [minitech (now u2744-snowflake)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/160410/u2744-snowflake?tab=bounties&sort=offered) :D

Answer (score 116, accepted):

> Is there some advantage to having these points that I'm not aware of?

Sure. The more reputation you have, the more you can participate in and moderate the site.

Reputation is directly tied in to the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) one can gain on the site.

---

> I feel I must be missing something here

Given that downvotes indicate something wrong/bad in the post, yes, it makes sense for people to worry about them. They are a strong signal that something isn't right. They are tied to negative reputation so people actually pay attention.

---

Now, if you are asking why do people care about imaginary Internet points, I can't help with that. People care about imaginary points everywhere - playing games and more.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you can spend reputation as bounty for questions with "hard" problems.

Comment: @honk: But bounty itself is again just reputation points. So if people do not care about reputation the ability to set a bounty is pretty useless.

Comment: Bounties are useful because *other* people care about reputation, @Karolis. Of course, they also make a question more prominent.

Comment: Money is the biggest imaginary point out there and people care about it very much...

Comment: No it is NOT imaginary. You can literally move mountains with money!

Comment: The problem isn't so much downvoting, but people downvoting not based on answer/question quality but for reasons of personal opinion or just to prevent someone from getting higher rep than themselves. Think all the C++ fanboyz serially downvoting anything that's in the least positive about Java (not so much now, but few years ago was a real problem).

Comment: @TRiG: [setting a bounty increases views count for your question but it won't give you better answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272879/4279) i.e., it might be due to the people who matter (capable of answering "hard" questions) do not care about the rep. There are exceptions.

Comment: People care about the points because they are perceived as a proxy to their *status*, and most people (especially male) instinctively care about that. Points are widely accepted as reflecting status of other members. Getting a negative score on an answer is perceived as losing face in public---a big deal (on the instinctive level).

Comment: You cannot move mountains with money, people or machines move it for MONEY. Where we again get back to people who care about money

Comment: @Vigabrand: No. You can literally move mountains with dynamite. It would take a while with a dollar bill, and I think it would wear out.

Comment: @darknight That is like saying "You cannot move your arm, only the muscles in your arm and shoulder can". Money determines whether you can move a mountain. If you have it, people and machines will be willing to help. If not, good luck.

Comment: Well the fact that currency was created to represent money is enough evidence to show that it wasn't real!

Answer (score 149):

I'd like to throw my hat in the ring on this question.

### Developers are not often thanked for the thing they want to be thanked for the most

As developers we rarely get a direct thank you from anyone on figuring out a complex problem quickly. Business users rarely pat you on the back and tell you that your algorithm for determining the best way to compare apples and oranges was exactly what they were looking for. It's less about the points themselves and more about the feeling of accomplishment when you help someone with a complex problem, and large amount of upvotes makes the accolades seem even more plentiful. Yay accolades!

### Developers are rarely "just done" with something

Developers spend a lot of time hammering out lame forms and doing back end work that never seems to end and takes a week or two to complete. Stack answers (and questions) are easy, digestible ways to get a feeling of completion, and it's much easier to say that an accepted answer is done and you'll never have to look at it again.

### Stack accounts are public and can be used to display competence for your career

I'd love to hit 10k before I move to my next position, and I'll list it on my resume. That shows I have some level of communication skill with fellow developers, and that I contribute positively in an environment where I know nothing and have to quickly understand a possibly complex situation.

### We want powers

Big rep means big responsibilities, and eventual sorta-modship, only this isn't because I know bob and tim and they can get me there. You get mod powers because you deserve them for your contributions to the community. You **earn** privileges.

### It's a community

And we like to be liked! Some people equate internet points to personal validation, which is fine. But it may also cloud their judgement as to how important the points really are.

Edit: As an aside, I'm even excited that this post is getting upvotes, **and I don't even earn reputation for it**. So, it's not all about the points sometimes!

Comment: `Stack answers (and questions) are easy, digestible ways to get a feeling of completion` -> exactly my motivation, it is MUCH easier than my main job, yet I make someone's life better.

Comment: This post made me wish I could award bounties on MSO. Well put! :)

Comment: Very well written. Upvotes really bring a lot of happiness, even on meta.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I agree, reputation points help in feeling more confident as a developer. The fact that you can solve problems (not just your own) is what makes you a programmer!

Comment: +1k `Developers are not often thanked for the thing they want to be thanked for the most`

Comment: [They should learn to say thank you to coders](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2013/05/30/manque-de-reconnaissance/)

Comment: @Unihedron That comic is great because it highlights our experience as developers, but we're already deep in the rabbit hole of having a lot of technical knowledge. See http://coding2learn.org/blog/2013/07/29/kids-cant-use-computers/, especially the portion where he gives you a situation and says "He/she can't use a computer." These are real people that we expect to pat us on the back when we're done with something. They don't even know how to use computers, can we really expect them to understand what it means to cut three days off the development time?

Comment: This post deserves a website all of its own, along the lines of whathaveyoutried.com and sscce.org. Maybe called. howtomakeyourdeveloperhappy.com

Comment: +1: Specifically for this: `Stack accounts are public and can be used to display competence for your career`. I've had potential employers look through my SO profile to gauge how I problem solve and communicate solutions. A healthy SO rep and cadre of questions/answers is enormously powerful as its own indicator of actual capability beyond a standard resume/CV.

Comment: It can also ruin your chances for a job based on the time you post.  If I, as a hypothetical hiring manager, see that most of your posts are made during business hours, that means you're helping other people instead of doing your job while I'm paying you to do it.    Don't get me wrong, I think it's normal and correct to use biz time for sites like this, in moderate amounts.   10k, though?  Sounds like productivity issues may exist if I hire you.

Comment: @briansol I also answer questions on the weekend ;)

Answer (score 34):

Get points, save the day, get the girl, profit. Isn't it obvious? I've got more rep than @Coffee, so I'm obviously cooler and smarter. William has a bit more rep than me, but I can catch up. Oded has more rep than I'll collect in a lifetime, so I'll either kiss his *** so I'm in the cool crowd or I'll rebel it out and find a way to put him down because I'm secretly jelluz.

See more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competition

Comment: I agree with you that some people take StackOverflow as a competitive playground and too seriously sometimes. Also, the voting system is far from perfect, any $%&$% can get 500 rep to moderate. On the other hand I completely share Infinite Recursion's thought. The benefits you get in learning and sharing knowledge are worth the hassle.

Comment: I was once upon a time one such person (one who took a little too seriously). It is fun, you learn and share and you get rewarded with recognition for it. Sure you encounter some people you don't get along with, but that's not stackoverflow, that's just life. :)

Comment: My answer isn't technically accurate. It should say "get the girl, StackExchange profits." They profit off the content that we create in exchange for imaginary gain (points). They get money, we get more ego. :)

Comment: Excuse me, but if you're cooler than Coffee, I'd choose Coffee over you any day! What do you taste like anyway?

Comment: A lot of people on this site with big rep take themselves way too seriously. After a recent experience here that I am going to check people's rep before hiring them from now on. Too many points, instant disqual. Egomanics can take a hike, regardless of skill.

Comment: @BrianTopping There are some people with high rep that are decent people, then again there are some who are, as you put it, egomaniacs. But to be honest with you, I've experienced the same ratio of good/bad even in lower ranks. From my own experiences, this is is an industry specific problem. I personally hate working for/with other people in companies because no matter how hard you try to just get work done, 99% of time is wasted on **** swinging.

Comment: @BrianTopping It's incredibly difficult I think to judge how someone will perform in an IT job, which I think is a major problem in the industry. At my last job at a tech company, I watched the "tech lead" for a billion dollar website repeatedly point at a for loop he drew on the whiteboard and call it a recursive function. Somebody probably had a "system" that decided he was qualified too. Anyway my point is that I understand and sympathize with your experience, but disagree with your conclusion. :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: Appreciate your perspective and the time you put into wording it.The type of person I am referring to is almost always "last seen" within the last ten minutes and has the letter "k" in their reputation count. Their posts are impeccable so that they might have no problem badgering others whose posts do not conform to their own precise standards. Agree that this is not a standalone indicator, but this is now a huge red flag for me. Firing is a lot harder than hiring for absolutely everyone involved.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: SO/SE started as such a great place. Quantitative meritocracy is such a noble idea, but it's turned so technocratic that it's become an elitist tool rather than one that can truly help others to grow and move the industry forward together. It saddens me to say that because a friend I care about works there and I don't have a lot of hope right now.

Answer (score 24):

**Sense of achievement**

Yup, it's fun as hell to gain those points & [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Competing with friends & family is great too. Gamification at it's best :)

**[Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)**

The more you invest, the more the site trusts you, the more you can do. Plain simple.

**CV for works**

I gained my 1k rep for fun, but believe it or not, it'll help you in your real life as well. Last week I applied for a job and sent the Boss my SO Profile via Facebook. He was excited that I am successfully part of this community, there is no doubt it helped me make an impression.

Comment: Your imaginary internet point count is currently 1337. This must *never change*! :P

Comment: CV for works is spot on. It's actually a KPI for my job to show that I am actively contributing to the development community, and SO rep is one way of showing that. Other examples could be guest-lecturing at the university, facilitating/contributing to workshops and cross-skill sessions with partner firms.

Comment: @Doorknob ^^, we should all do our part by *never ever* voting on my Q&A's again.

Answer (score 11):

> Why do people care about reputation points?

Honestly, I don't know.

> Why do I care about reputation points ?

My first motivation to get reputation points here was to put a bounty on my [very first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880302/customizing-the-scrollbar-programmatically).

Now that I have enough rep to put huge bounties on many questions, I'm still interested by those *imaginary internet points*. Why?

When I spend some time in a contribution here it is mainly for one reason : I hope (and I believe) that what I'm writing will be useful to others. (SO is the most useful site in my job every day... so contributing positively is nothing more than giving back what I receive from this site)

When I receive +10 rep for one of my contribution, it is like a confirmation that I wasn't wrong : "what I wrote is useful to someone... that was my primary goal."

Additionally, the total reputation represent also kind of "peers recognition". IMHO this recognition is something important too keep motivation in my daily job. Let's say that it gives me the feeling that "I'm not that bad at programming."

Do I **really** care about rep ? No, not *really*... it is just kind of artificial reward for an unpaid work.

Comment: It sure is frustrating to spend some time coming up with a good answer (nowadays this may include finding out how to create an animated GIF of a process--as I did yesterday), putting it into writing, going over it several times .. and then, nothing. No upvotes? Not even *downvotes*? Helloo-oo?

Comment: @Jongware: that is because you are not writing one-liners that an average joe can read and partially understand...

Comment: @Jongware Although I'm still fairly new to SE, I can relate to that. A few of my answers have involved quite a bit of time researching & coding - I put that effort in because I was interested in improving my own understanding of the topic, so I don't consider it time wasted. But to get nothing in response, not even a comment, is a bit uninspiring...

Comment: And then when I get 4 or 5 upvotes on an easy-to-understand "throw-away" answer that took me maybe 2 minutes to write, it tempts me to avoid the tricky technical questions and just go for the "low hanging fruit". Although you do have to be _very_ quick to be the first to answer those ones. :)

Answer (score 7):

Some time ago I said to myself that I want to give something back to the community after years of "unpaid" usage of SO. So I started answering questions. But that was not enough. Especially at the beginning without all the necessary priviledges to really participate. So I wanted to reach at least 50 rep so I can comment everywhere. Then I saw 125 rep for down-voting and said to myself, I've got to have that otherwise you can't "mark" bad content.

Now I'm eager to get 10k for more moderation priviledges, but this will be a long journey and I doubt that I will stop answering questions when I reach that goal.

Gratitude in the form of rep is really nice for my peace of mind.

Answer (score 6):

IMO the main value of rep is so that I can give it away as bounties.  Though I will admit it was a bit embarrassing when I got downvoted 11 times on [apparently terrible question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240737/question-closed-by-votes-from-people-who-do-not-appear-to-be-familiar-with-the-t)

Comment: _"when I got downvoted 11 times on apparently terrible question"_ Don't wake sleeping dogs ;-P ...

Answer (score 5):

Gaining those points has a couple of advantages. It is, of course, a great way to impress family, friends and co-workers. I mean, who hasn't bragged about their reputation to a random aunt at a birthday party? ;-)

You get more privileges on the site, which is a good thing if you like to feel in control. You can see the amount of upvotes and downvotes, and you can see deleted answers, which might sometimes shine some light on an otherwise confusing thread. Then again, those privileges are about as useful as the points themselves. Will it help *you* to be able to edit a question? If you don't care about the points, you probably also don't care about many of those privileges.

One possibility you gain, is to set a bounty on a question, which will attract other people who also care about reputation. Your question will be more visible and is more likely to be answered, so the reputation you gain is also a currency with which you can 'buy' expertise from others.

There is another real life advantage. Your answers and their score result in a showcase of your capabilities, which can attract offers from companies through StackOverflow Careers.

Those, for me, are reasons to care about points. Now, my goal isn't really to search for questions that will get me the most reputation. I'm perfectly fine with a single vote, and I got quite a couple of accepted answers with no votes at all (Unsung Hero badge). So personally I care more about getting my answer accepted than getting loads of points. To me, an accepted answer indicates that I understood the problem and was able to give an answer that solved the problem and was written at the right level of understanding.

*Executive summary:*

So to sum up: Points are good for social status, site privileges, online showcase resulting in real-life job opportunities and acknowledgement/appreciation by peers. Some people won't care for any of these, and others might value any combination of these factors.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that I am getting better answers now that my rep is not too low.
Perhaps I am biased and that I simply have learnt to phrase my questions properly, but I can't help notice that very low rep users tend to be told to do their homeworks.. In short, my question simply gets read, and I get advice on how to improve it.

Several others have mentioned showing off their rep to a potential employer. I think it is a double edged sword. Some may conclude that you're spending more time levelling up than actually working.

Answer (score 4):

> I feel I must be missing something here

You are just missing the quality time in thinking about this. Make use of the time to provide quality answers, make useful edits, improvise etc.

The points? Well, if you do what I said above, you need not worry about points. ***You would get them anyway!***

**NOTE** :

***If gaining points is the ONLY goal to participate, then the basic purpose of this beautiful and useful site, is defeated.***

Answer (score 3):

We like to feel useful in this uncertain world. Upvotes = usefulness.

Comment: They're actually more akin to "likes."

Comment: So, is John Skeet the most _useful_ person in the world?

Comment: @honk Not a person. A god.

Comment: @bjb568: Lets agree on SO's personal god ;)

Comment: @honk - no, You mistake up/down votes to be personal. Instead they give an indication about the quality of questions and answers.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: This sounds as if the quality of questions and answers has no correlation to the person who writes them ;)

Comment: @honk: Well, there is some correlation, but it can be rather loose. Eg, a person might get downvotes for answering a bad question, even though the answer would be considered good in another context. So that's a reflection on their ability to refrain from answering a bad question just because they can, rather than a reflection on their programming or explanation skills. And there's also the phenomenon that Jongware mentioned in ben75's answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I agree, but I think that the cases you mention are exceptions. They become statistically less relevant the more useful questions and answers a person posts. At least I hope so.

Answer (score 3):

I want to improve the site.

I originally wanted enough rep to be able to submit edits.  Then I wanted to be able to cast downvotes and participate in fixing the review queue.  Now I am working towards the coveted "golden badger hammer" in one of the tags I'm active in.

I see you already received a lot of good answers, but I didn't see this aspect covered enough. Sure, several of these answers talk about "unlocking privileges" but if you don't care about interacting with this site specifically, why do you care about privileges?

Answer (score 3):

It has a lot to do:

**FIRST** it's a personal evaluation to know where you are know:

- **are you** still a noob that is not consider a developer yet? and still asking a basic questions and still can't give a mid-level answer?
- **are you** asking a more professional questions that can came from a real developer?
- **are you** asking a valuable questions that make a lot of developers gain benefits from it?
- **are you** now a real professional software developer that can reach things others can't?

**SECOND** it gives the other a general idea about you(I do saw a lot of companies asking for links of SO & LinkedIn accounts beside your CV in their vacant announcement)

**THIRD** depending on how powerful you are, you can be banned from asking questions on SO anymore, you can be a regular person asking and answering, you can be a person who can review other posts and make changes to it besides closing or opening questions, or you can be a moderator who participating in moderating SO.

Answer (score 3):

Its like an addiction, when I enter the site and see a green box indicating I earned some new points my brain gets some rewards, this joy makes it more eager to see this green box again and again. (the addiction process)

At first months this addiction is high but after awhile it may decrease and you get satisfied with your current level of points and concern more about what you have learned or the quality of your answers or even your time and your duties and aims in real life.

I mean being addicted to anything could be bad, that could be a game, sports, TV... and gaining more points on SE.

you should try to learn from your negative points and positive points but don't get addicted to them. However, seeing that green box is always delightful!

Answer (score 2):

Just some addition to all the great answers pointing out **privileges and public display of competence and merit**:

**SO relies heavily on sorting of questions and above all of answers by public voting.** Obviously higher voted answers will be regarded with more goodwill and will be read first and probably more often. Therefore answerers care about the score and try to give not only a good answer but often also an excellent answer. It is a key element of the high quality here.

And then these scores are aggregated to give a reputation. That part is not so interesting to me and I could live very well with a view of SO where the peoples rep is not displayed at all. I think I mostly treat everyone the same although I honor participation i.e. people with many useful answers. I see repuation mostly as an **aggregate measure of participation**. But I was surprised by all the funny badges you can obtain. I guess the reason for that is solely **gamification**. It's just a game. Nothing more. You can safely ignore but in case it motivates you, be proud of every award and every reputation point you can get.

One of these days I will write a user script that hides the repetition of people.

Answer (score 2):

Reputation points are one proxy for validation.

We all want some recognition that our thoughts and ideas resonate with others.  An up-vote signals that our idea was correct to some degree.  Just as responses to your question validate the question itself.  (If you thought that posting your question would solicit nothing but silence, why put the effort in posting it?)

It's all part of being a social animal.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything Oded said.

I think also, concept of gamification. This is human behavior - we like "achievements" and "points". We enjoy the reputation and good word of peers.

From the beginning, Stack Overflow included gamification. You unlock privileges and earn badges.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I care *a bit* because you need reputation to start bounties. Using SO as a development tool, there are objective benefits to rep

- Starting bounties on questions that are important to you
- Privileges on SO. I rarely use these "similar question, close request, etc."
- Some employees allow you to submit your SO profile, and a high rep *could* help you in a hiring situation

With less rep, it's harder to start a bounty, and harder to get a great answer to a problem you have. That in itself is valuable to me. Hell, I'd purchase "bounty-use-only-rep" if that was a thing so I can get the answers I need.

Of course there are some subjective reasons including one's own ego, but I personally don't care about that.

Answer (score 0):

When I mention in my resume that I'm in the *TOP 200* on Stack Overflow I expect them to at least invite me.

Comment: FFM? Greetings from OF ;)

Comment: Not sure what you're saying...

Comment: Was this your intention to join Stack Overflow?

Comment: @LalitKumarB no. I did not realize this. If I was interested in picking up more work I certainly would create a great account and use it, though.

Answer (score 0):

As a freelancer / contractor, reputation on a site which is as well known and respected as SO can translate into a real competitive edge when trying to edge out others on a new project or consulting opportunity.

Although personally, I would try to provide links to a handful of specific samples of my answers which demonstrate a decent understanding on a  relevant topic or technology, there is no doubt that the pure quantity of rep also counts toward this bias (and tag counts can quickly give an idea of a candidates strengths and weaknesses).

Relative rep counts in particular tag categories are especially important - e.g. to be able to say your are in the top 5% of `COBOL-80` or the 5th to reach a gold in `LOLCODE` makes a a compelling case when the job spec calls for these skills.

Similarly, downvotes for hasty, or ill-researched answers can have real negative consquences - although the Rep loss is minor, the permanent nature of even a deleted answer can serve as a deterrent to a would-be employer (= candidate is hasty, guesses, takes risks, etc, assuming the employer has access to the 10k views).

The success of the sister site `Careers @ StackExchange` serves as proof that employers (and the recruitment industry) has cottoned onto the relative value of SO reputation.

**Edit**
Sadly, there also seems to be a [black market in SO rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270795/is-it-legitimate-to-buy-stack-overflow-reputation) - at ~US 0.30 per point. Hopefully this can be snipped in the bud.

Comment: What the heck is COBOL-80?

Comment: The languages quoted were simply facetious examples of interesting languages to allow me to get my point across, and neither of which I have any knowledge whatsoever :)

Answer (score -5):

If you want to get a job in the meta industry, a prospective employer might check your meta.stackoverflow reputation when considering your application.

Comment: man, i have been trying to break into the meta industry for years...