# Why was my flag requesting to reopen the question declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Some time ago, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275369/why-do-people-care-about-reputation-points) question was closed as off-topic. I couldn't vote to reopen it as I don't have sufficient reputation, so I flagged it to be reopened.

> [image]

The question was reopened (not by a mod), flag was, however, declined. Why? This question *did* require intervention... Maybe there is another reason?

Comment: As pointed out in the answers and in the help centre flags should not be used for reopening. I found the help centre unclear on this point - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377200/what-should-i-consider-before-posting-a-question-about-a-specific-question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moderator flags should not be used for things that the community can do - they should be used for things that **require** moderator attention.

As the blog article [A Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) described, moderators are "human exception handlers" and should be called upon as little as possible.

In this case - the community closed and the community can decide to reopen.

That the outcome may go against your own wishes is not a good enough reason to call upon the moderators.

Comment: but I can flag for closure and it doesn't always requesting mod intervention...

Comment: Close flags are handled by the community, through the review queues.

Comment: oh yes, holes in my old memory, I even review them myself on mse sometimes :D but why can't there be reopen flags then?

Comment: It is more important to get bad/unsuitable questions closed than to reopen closed questions that are now deemed good (one reopen vote will place the post in the reopen queue).

Comment: @nicael There is no need for reopen-flags: Just edit it so no close-reason any longer applies (and especially not whatever close-reason lead to closing), and it will automatically be put into the reopen-queue (which in contrast to the close-queue in not overflowing).

Comment: @Ded on persite meta I can't btw.

Comment: @nicael: Well, if you cannot edit someone else's question (and as on per-site metas suggestions are disabled), you really need to get someone else to edit it. Maybe not being quite that allergic to rep would help ;-)

Comment: @Ded ohwait. thisis idea. I'll think about it ;)

Comment: @Ded [I took your advice](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=reputation) :)

Answer (score 7):

The question didn't require *moderator* intervention because the question could be, and was, reopened by non-moderators.

Moderators are there to handle problems that cannot be resolved by non-moderators, and this is not such a problem.

Comment: but wait, sometimes I do raise flags requesting closure, but closure also doesn't require mod intervention...

Comment: @nicael Those flags aren't handled by mods; it just puts it into the Close Vote review queue. An "Other" flag *always* goes to the mods.

Comment: @bradley, damn, I confused myself. close are not other flags. but why isn't there an ability to flag for reopening

Comment: @nicael See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/can-we-have-the-ability-to-flag-for-reopening And note that you *can* use an "Other" flag, but probably shouldn't. Yours was particularly bad: "It is on-topic" doesn't tell a moderator what you think they should do.