# Flag to reopen (suggested by the help center) declined

Tags: support, declined-flags, help-center

I raised a flag to reopen a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30567687/1761793) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDWas.png)), as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) in the help center:

> Flag the question for moderator attention. Again, explain why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.

But my flag was declined with this message:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

What went wrong here?

1. Is this particular information in the help center wrong?
2. A moderator (human) mistake.

I saw this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275729/1761793), but it does not fully answer my question.

---

<sub>PS:- I extracted this question from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296120/1761793), as I felt clubbing this question with the former did not bring this the proper attention.</sub>

Comment: On what grounds did you suggest to the moderator to reopen? The question could be closed as too broad or unclear, since there is no code.

Comment: Duplicate meta question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296120/472495

Comment: @halfer I asked a new question, because I wanted an answer for "why the Help Center directs me to raise a flag, if it is not required?"

Comment: OK. On any SE site, if you ask a question very similar to one of your previous questions, please link to the related question (perhaps at the beginning or the end of the post) and explain how your new question differs. This helps to show that you are not simply just reposting in order to get new answers.

Comment: Moved back my answer here and reopened. It's a bit of a mess between the two posts.

Comment: @halfer I did. But perhaps I could have been clearer.

Comment: @donald-duck: The newly linked webarchive version is misleading since it doesn't display the correct version. It shows revision 1 from June 1 '15. At the point when this question has been asked revision 4 from June 5 '15 was relevant. I think that pushing a 2 year old post to the front-page by editing a link for <10k users is rather useless anyway.

Comment: @BDL Could you please provide a screenshot of the correct version then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I declined the flag because these days reopening is handled by the community; editing the post puts the post into the review queue where it is then voted on for reopening. In the meantime the community had also *deleted* the post.

The [review outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/8305565) was to leave the post closed, and I saw no reason to go against that decision. You edited the post *after* I declined the flag.

Custom flags are still fine but should detail why a moderator should intervene; e.g. why should the community decision be overruled?

Note that the post was not closed by a moderator; it was closed by 5 community members; the help centre article you found does not apply here.

Comment: So the help center is correct. But I still feel the message should have been different. Something like '*a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*' informs me that my action was valid, but not the reopening of the question.

Comment: @Ajoy no, your action was not correct. The post was never closed by a moderator alone.