# How efficient is a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

In my opinion, the only reason [my question about Spaceship AI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623315/ai-of-spaceships-propulsion-land-a-3d-ship-at-position-0-and-angle-0) has no answer is that it is really hard and also require a lot of effort to answer. (No?)

Now, I am considering to put a bounty on it.

**Question:**

- How efficient is a bounty?
- More specifically, what increase in views from bounty can I expect? (+50%?)
- How much does it increase the probability that a good answer will appear?
- How much difference is there in attention gained between a bounty of +50 and +100?

I want an approximation, i.e. an answer by feeling is OK.

Comment: Some time ago, I did some [research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329185/do-bounties-attract-upvotes-or-is-this-just-a-coincidence/329199#329199) on the effects of bounties to up- and downvotes.

Comment: [This question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272879/how-much-do-bounties-increase-the-likelihood-of-getting-a-good-acceptable-answer/273070#273070) and its answers seem to have a lot of information you want.

Comment: Bounties let good questions come up to the top, and bad questions sink.

Comment: I have the idea that people who are looking to truly answer things in-depth look only to higher bounties expecting them to be the more serious questions worth their time. Basically anyone can slap a 50 rep bounty on a question of any level of quality just to lure people in for quick help.

Comment: javaLover, can you indicate which part of the information you're looking for is *not* in the questions I linked? If those contain everything you need, this question is better closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The question you are considering offering a bounty on seems a little broad to me. Also, is it on topic for Stack Overflow? Assuming it is on topic and not too broad, I would say a bounty would help your question. A high bounty might motivate some smart people to give a thoughtful answer. Another option is to do a 50, 100, 200 three week bounty series for maximum views. Sometimes even poor answers help you consider things you hadn't thought about before.

Comment: @Glorfindel   Your sources are really useful.   The only remaining question is difference between +50 and +100. I also like your editing. Thank!

Comment: You're welcome. I did some further analysis, see my answer below. Having seen the results, I like the cascading bounty solution proposed by Suragch (if you can spare the reputation, of course).

Comment: Bounties were created for Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As indicated in your comment, most of the information was already covered in earlier questions. As for the specific difference between a 50- and a 100-point bounty, it is **not that much**. I composed a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/580631/how-much-views-do-bounties-generate-on-posts) which counts the number of views on a question grouped by bounty amount, which is the yellow line in the picture below. As you can see, there is not much difference between +50 (904 views) and +100 (965 views), but you never know if the answer(er) you're looking for is within that difference.

[image: graph with SEDE data]

The blue line is the actual number of bounties of that size (divided by 10 for scaling purposes). Higher bounties are rarer, so the data becomes less reliable. Common sense suggests a +450 cannot be less effective than a +100 bounty. You can [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/580631) the query to analyze different time periods.

Answer (score 3):

*Non-professional answer here.* based on personal experience, if you put a bounty on a popular topic it will get crazy views / answers. if you put it on a not well known topic, its almost useless.

for example:

I had two bounties regarding selenium / chrome flags, neither got that much views or answers. The other day i had a bounty on a javascript question and it got exponential increase in views and answers.